# Need advice on suitable message queue for Storm spout

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, amqp, apache-storm

I'm developing a prototype [Lambda system](http://www.manning.com/marz/BD_meap_ch01.pdf) and my data is streaming in via Flume to HDFS.  I also need to get the data into Storm.  Flume is a push system and Storm is more pull so I don't believe it's wise to try to connect a spout to Flume, but rather I think there should be a message queue between the two.  Again this is a prototype, so I'm looking for best practices, not perfection.  I'm thinking of putting an AMQP compliant queue as a Flume sink and then pulling the messages from a spout.

Is this a good approach?  If so, I want to use a message queue that has relatively robust support in both the Flume world (as a sink) and the Storm world (as a spout).  If I go AMQP then I assume that gives me the option to use whatever AMQP-compliant queue I want to use, correct?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to use AMQP, I'd recommend sticking to the finalized 1.0 version of the AMQP spec.  Otherwise, your going to feel some pain when you try to upgrade to it from previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach makes a lot of sense, but, for us the AMQP compliant issue looked a little less important. I will try to explain why.

We are using Kafka to get data into storm. The main reason is mainly around performance and usability. AMQP complaint queues do not seem to be designed for holding information for a considerable time, while with Kafka this is just a definition. This allows us to keep messages for a long time and allow us to "playback" those easily (as the message we wish to consume is always controlled by the consumer we can consume the same messages again and again without a need to set up an entire system for that purpose). Also, Kafka performance is incomparable to anything that I have seen.

Storm has a very useful KafkaSpout, in which the main things to pay attention to are:

1. Error reporting - there is some improvement to be done there. Messages are not as clear as one would have hoped.
2. It depends on zookeeper (which is already there if you have storm) and a path is required to be manually created for it.
3. According to the storm version, pay attention to the Kafka version in use. It is documented, but, can really easily be missed and cause unclear problems.

Comment: +1 to Kafka. The currently available "official" KafkaSpout works with Kafka 0.7.x (the latest stable version of Kafka) and Storm 0.8 and 0.9.  There does not seem to be a spout implementation available for Kafka 0.8 -- I have only seen a first draft implementation on GitHub by Chris Curtin (see [mailing list message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/storm-user/cGBiFzApYdk/JhRne6SxK3gJ) and his [storm-kafka fork](https://github.com/ChrisCurtin/storm-contrib/tree/master/storm-kafka) on GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

You can have the data streamed to a broker topic first. Then flume and storm spout can both consume from that topic. Flume has a jms source that makes it easy to consume from the message broker. And a storm jms spout to get the messages into storm.